# Accelerometer, gyro, and magnetometer sensor fusion for material resource survey

Tags: control, kalman-filter, imu, calibration, precise-positioning

As a hardware engineer, I have studied quite a lot on sensor spec such as Accel, Gyro and Magnetometer including custom made fluxgate. I have studied matrix and quadarion (complex number) and so on.
I moving into calibration arena, I seen lot of article on calibration but not sure which is best solution to fix offset and mis-alignment axis. Can anyone point to best open source code.
I'm not interested in output results related to flight such as quadchopter and GPS, but more interested in directional math for drilling pipes, where toolface, inclination, azimuth and position is most important. What the best thesis or paper that cover this topic and open-source or example code (in C) for this application. Do I need Kalnman filter or such advance post data capture processing. Any tip how to avoid getting too involved with maths

Comment: Some IMU's have their own calibration process and sample code which can be found on their respective datasheets/appnotes. This may vary depending on the manufacturer (STmicro and Freescale in particular have done a great job with some of their MEM's) :)